# Is it possible to connect to a hosted Oracle Cloud database using Python (cx_oracle)?

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to gain access to a database hosted at oraclecloud.com - is this possible? I.e. assuming I have the correct login credentials, is it possible to access the data from the database using cx_oracle when the database is hosted out of my reach? If so, does anyone have any sample code?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you have the login credentials, and the hosted database allows connection from your ip address then you can use cx_oracle to connect to it. There is no further python code needed. You should check how your database allows connection. Possibly you'll need to create an SSH tunnel, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/database-dbaas-cloud/csdbi/create-ssh-tunnel.html#GUID-6929CE39-6CD7-46C9-8022-929A9844B1C5

Comment: Thank you Karl, that's very helpful.